# Change Windows ACLs of SMB Samba Shares - directly in linux

Tags: linux, samba, network-share, access-control-list

Is there a way to set the Windows ACLs from files and folders of an Samba Share directly through Linux itself?

I know there is the option setfacl/getfacl but they can only change between: - DENY | READ-ONLY | FULL-Control - if I got this right.

But I need for a Windows Security Group modify rights. And that recursively to all following directories. If I would change this from windows directly through an SMB connection this would take hours and days because of the mass of files. Is there a way to do this or is it still not possible? I know the information is stored anywhere in the share cause I can copy files in Linux to the share folder and they get automatically the previously chosen modify rights.

To avoid the change of settings through SMB, I out copy the files from the share. Delete all files in the share and change the permissions from windows on the share.

```
Actually this is how I proceeding so far:

In Linux:

1. I copy files and folders from the share folder to a separate location.
2. I delete all stuff in the share folder.

In Windows:

3. Then accessing the empty share folder through SMB.
4. From here I can change recursively the permissions for access groups to apply "modify" permissions.


Back in Linux:

5. Now I can copy the files and folders back into the share folder to set the permissions.
```

-> The files got through the copy process the new permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running Samba 4, the commands **samba-tool ntacl** could certainly do it.

Unfortunately it's quite hard to find detailed doc on how to use this command to set ACLs:

```
#samba-tool ntacl set -h
Usage: samba-tool ntacl set <acl> <file> [options]

Set ACLs on a file.


Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --quiet               Be quiet
  --xattr-backend=XATTR_BACKEND
                        xattr backend type (native fs or tdb)
  --eadb-file=EADB_FILE
                        Name of the tdb file where attributes are stored
  --use-ntvfs           Set the ACLs directly to the TDB or xattr for use with
                        the ntvfs file server
  --use-s3fs            Set the ACLs for use with the default s3fs file server
                        via the VFS layer
  --service=SERVICE     Name of the smb.conf service to use when applying the
                        ACLs

  Samba Common Options:
    -s FILE, --configfile=FILE
                        Configuration file
    -d DEBUGLEVEL, --debuglevel=DEBUGLEVEL
                        debug level
    --option=OPTION     set smb.conf option from command line
    --realm=REALM       set the realm name

  Credentials Options:
    --simple-bind-dn=DN
                        DN to use for a simple bind
    --password=PASSWORD
                        Password
    -U USERNAME, --username=USERNAME
                        Username
    -W WORKGROUP, --workgroup=WORKGROUP
                        Workgroup
    -N, --no-pass       Don't ask for a password
    -k KERBEROS, --kerberos=KERBEROS
                        Use Kerberos
    --ipaddress=IPADDRESS
                        IP address of server
    -P, --machine-pass  Use stored machine account password

  Version Options:
    -V, --version       Display version number
```

I would suggest you this procedure:

```
# 1)
# In Windows
# Go to one shared folder/file and change the permissions as desired

#2)
# In Linux
# Get infos of the ACLs of the directory/file you just set up in SDDL format

#samba-tool ntacl get --as-sddl /path/to/my/share
O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU)

#3)
# Use the SDDL parameter to change all the files you want with same ACL

# samba-tool ntacl set "O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU)" /path/to/other/files
```

Detail:

```
samba-tool ntacl get --as-sddl [file/directory]
```

will get ACLs infos in SDDL format. More on SDDL [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379567(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
samba-tool ntacl set "[SDDL string]" [file/directory]
```

will apply specified ACL on the file/folder

The solution is not perfect tough it could help you.

About samba-tool commands:
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/samba-tool.8.html

A related issue on Samba mail lists:
https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2011-October/079820.html

Comment: That's just nasty...  haha   ;-)